# How does `flux`/`mono`, RabbitMQ, AkkaStream work in big picture in microservies world?

Tags: java, mono, rabbitmq, flux, akka-stream

i try to grasp what are flux and mono for in big picture.

I get that when microservices talk to each other we can you use quee (like `RabbitMQ`) to make them talk asynchronously instead of synchronously.

But if i use only `flux`/`mono` using `HTTP2` (to my knowledge) then my microservies already talk to each other asynchronously or not?

If not then what part of the big picture is asynchronous?

There is also `Akka streams` - is it something like RabbitMQ? A quee that make microservies talk asynchronously?

I would appreciate clarification - thanks.

Comment: `akka-stream` is not implementation of queue. It's library for asynchronous transformation of streams in a pipelined fashion. So it can be used with RabbitMQ as well.

Comment: @expert so it's more like `RxJava`.